# JPA Spring repository filtering multiple parameters

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am using a Spring repository as follows in order to filter by date range

```
public interface CustomerRepo extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {

    public List<Customer> findByCreatedBetween(LocalDate start, LocalDate end);
}
```

it is ridiculous simple and is working fine, but now I need to expand my rest service to keep into account other filter criterias, for example sorted o not sorted, o filter by city and by country. When invoking the service, some parameters may be set and others not. Of course I cannot create a method like findByCreatedBetween to keep into account all possible data combinations. What is the best way to handle this scenario ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this post:

http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-four-jpa-criteria-queries/

You can also implement your repositories "the old way", that is, injecting the entityManager into your repo and creating a findByCriteria method that accepts a custom criteria object. Find here the criteria API docs: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html

Another alternative to criteria API would be using JPQL, in wich you create a dynamic query string from the same criteria. JPQL reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbtg.html

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to use `querydsl` and `predicates`.

There is a post which exactly describes some scenarions for building query langauge for a REST API using Spring Data and Querydsl. [tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-search-language-spring-data-querydsl)

Also here [there](https://github.com/thomasdarimont/sd-repositories-best-practices-javaland) is a very short description regarding querydsl and predicates (Step 8 Flexible Predicate execution)

He describes this scenario:

> **Requirement**: “As a user, I want to **search** for **customers by first name,
>   last name, email address** and **any combination** of them”

Comment: thanks for sharing. I cannot see any slide or presentation at that url, what do you mean with "Step 8 Flexible Predicate execution" ?

Comment: @BlackBishop yeah there are no slides but in code he documented the steps.